# write master's slave thread lag flapping

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

if I have two mysql hosts pointed at each other: host A and host B:

```
------> hostA(write co-master) 
| 
| 
| 
-----> hostB (read-only co-master)
```

why would hostA ever show replication delay when there's nothing being written to hostB? I'm seeing slave lag flap on occasion on my write master pointed to a read-only slave:

```
[root@db17 ~]# mysql -e "show slave status \G" | egrep "(Exec_Master_Log_Pos|Master_Log_File|Read_Master_Log_Pos|Seconds)"
          Master_Log_File: binary.108913
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 137400187
    Relay_Master_Log_File: binary.108913
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 137400187
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
[root@db17 ~]# mysql -e "show slave status \G" | egrep "(Exec_Master_Log_Pos|Master_Log_File|Read_Master_Log_Pos|Seconds)"
          Master_Log_File: binary.108913
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 137960791
    Relay_Master_Log_File: binary.108913
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 137960616
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 70
[root@db17 ~]# mysql -e "show slave status \G" | egrep "(Exec_Master_Log_Pos|Master_Log_File|Read_Master_Log_Pos|Seconds)"
          Master_Log_File: binary.108913
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 138609398
    Relay_Master_Log_File: binary.108913
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 138609398
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
```

https://gist.github.com/ethan-riskiq/11b88443450f3fc6e0f8003bda797824 for full slave status output. Running Percona mysql 5.7.25 with GTIDs enabled.

Comment: what s the binlog format and is log_slave_updates enabled on hostB?

Comment: binlog format is ROW. log_slave_updates are on for both hosts, since hostB is a hot standby for write master promotion

Comment: I have seen this problem (flapping slave delay) since the days of 4.0.  I have never found the cause, nor a solution.  I'll be there is even an antique bug report on the subject.  It always went away after a while.  Did yours go away?

Answer (score 1):

> why would hostA ever show replication delay when there's nothing being
>   written to hostB

Somewhat guessing:

Data is written to hostA -> replicated to hostB (and since log slave updates is enabled) -> replicated to hostA.

hostA sees that the transactions have its server-id and knows it does not need to apply them. However, it is still writing the data to the Relay_Master_Log_File (the examination of the server id is done in the sql thread).

hostA seems to be having i/o contention. Why?

1. Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
2. Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates